# When using and int to read character, why is the value 4096 + ascii

Tags: c, scanf

I was using gcc and was testing various ways to process characters using either integers or characters as the datatype.

```
int main() {
    int i;      
    printf("Enter a char: ");
    scanf(" %c", &i);
    printf("integer value= %d     char value=%c", i, i);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a char: f    
integer value= 4198     char value=f
```

I am curious about the integer value that is stored.  It looks like the value is equal to 4096 + ascii value of 'f'.

My question is why is 4096 added to the ascii value of the character?  What does that value represent?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code? It's important to see exactly what you're doing.

Comment: You would need to link code, but I'm guessing you're not setting your integer to zero before calling scanf and reading a char. Thus you have some junk undefined data. Post some code and we'll see...

Answer (score 4):

Type in the following program and you'll understand why:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int val = 4096;
    printf ("Enter your character: ");
    scanf ("%c",&val);
    printf ("integer val = %d, character val = %c\n", val, val);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this with `gcc -Wall` (all warnings), gives:

```
qq.c: In function 'main':
qq.c:6: warning: format '%c' expects type 'char *',
        but argument 2 has type 'int *'
```

(as good a reason as any for ensuring you enable all warnings when compiling) and running it gives the same results you found:

```
Enter your character: f
integer val = 4198, character val = f
```

The *reason* for this is the way `scanf` works combined with the way variables are laid out in memory.

That `scanf` will simply get a character and put it in memory. Because you've given it the address of an *integer*, and that integer is little-endian, it will only overwrite the least-significant byte (LSB) of that integer. Think of viewing that memory as an overlapped area and you'll see why:

```
    +--- The address passed to scanf.
    |
    V
+------+
| char |                       <-- Treated as char.
+------+------+------+------+
| lsb  |      |      | msb  |  <-- Treated as integer (assumes 32-bit).
+------+------+------+------+
```

Because `scanf` doesnt touch those rightmost bytes of the integer, they're left with whatever they held before the call. In my code, I explicitly force that to `4096` but, if your declaration is the uninitialised `int val;`, the contents will be indeterminate. In fact, when I remove the initialisation, I get `1629542246` (`0x6120D766` and you can still see the LSB set to `0x66` or `f`).

That just means my integer looked like this before the `scanf` call:

```
+------+
|  ??  |
+------+------+------+------+
|  ??  |  d7  |  20  |  61  |
+------+------+------+------+
```

and the `scanf` call only changed the `??` bit.

Comment: Thank you paxdiablo for your explanation.  I did not inititialize my variable and jumped to conclusions when I saw that the added value was 4096.  I tried it on a different machine and got a different value.

Answer (score 0):

Are you initializing the int before reading in the char? Could simply be an uninitialized value.
Can you show the code? What function are using the read the character into the int?

4096 is 0x00001000 in hex. Could be a flag or something before or after the character, or the number of characters read, depending on what you are using to read the character.

Comment: I did not initialize the int.  4096 was a chance value and I jumped to conclusions, thinking it might have had some sort of significance aside from being old junk data in memmory.